# Changing destination coordinates at runtime (Dynamically)

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, geolocation, android-gps

I want to program an Android application where *user A* can navigate it self to user B (using Google Maps and their Navigator). 
But I want my android application to update the coordinates of *user B* and send it to *user A* in real time.

**My question is:**  Are there any way for *user A* to retrieve the updated coordinates ***AND*** not getting a new route calculated every time that user B change its position?

Since I want my *user B* to send new coordinates every 15 meters, it would be hell if *user A* gets a new route calculated every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setDirection()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) method on the renderer and pass it to DirectionsResult. The DirectionsResult contains the result of the directions query, which you may either handle yourself which can automatically handle displaying the result on a map. The renderer is an MVCObject, it will automatically detect any changes to its properties and update the map when its associated directions have changed.

The following example calculates directions between two locations on Route, where the origin and destination are set by the given "start" and "end" values in the dropdown lists. The `DirectionsRenderer` handles display of the polyline between the indicated locations, and the placement of markers at the origin, destination and any waypoints, if applicable.

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I guess I need a webview inside my native android app to be able to render changing locations right? 
Or is it possible to send the controller and client (view) the new destination without a webview? 
Could you describe the first steps of using MVCObject for displaying Google Maps with navigation?

Comment: Here's a guide to extend MVObject: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: @user3506 did you get an answer to your question above?

Comment: Using setDirections causing refreshing the marker and which lead not smooth user exprience, You do have any way to smooth the expierence.